# GDI+ System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException On Image resize and conversion

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

The ImageHandler class is responsible for converting the image to jpg and 60x60 size, then it converts it to Base64. The first Image is fine but when I try to proccess another image in the same run it crashes.

```
class ImageHandler
    {
        public static void convertToFormat(string filename)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(@filename);
            var bitmap = ResizeImage(image, Globals.ImageSize, Globals.ImageSize);
            bitmap.Save(Globals.PRED_PATH, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
        {
             var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
             var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

             destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

             using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
             {
                 graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                 graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                 graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                 graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                 graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                 using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                 {
                     wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                     graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                 }
             }
            return destImage;
        }

        public static string ConvertImageToBase64String()
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(Globals.PRED_PATH);
            var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            var imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        }
    }
```

Function Call:

```
ImageHandler.convertToFormat(FilePath);
string encodedImage = ImageHandler.ConvertImageToBase64String();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you can add `image.Dispose();` after `image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);` in the method `ConvertImageToBase64String` to make it work.

However I would recommend that you add `using` statements to `convertToFormat` and `ConvertImageToBase64String` to properly free the resources after use.

```
public static void convertToFormat(string filename)
{
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(@filename))
    {
        using (var bitmap = ResizeImage(image, Globals.ImageSize, Globals.ImageSize))
        {
            bitmap.Save(Globals.PRED_PATH, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}

public static string ConvertImageToBase64String()
{
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(Globals.PRED_PATH))
    {
        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            var imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        }
    }
}
```